# Pulling raw_input options form a list

Tags: python, list, input

Hi I'm just starting to learn Python, I'm using the book "learn python the hard way" and one of the exercises is to build a simple game. I wanted to give options to the user from a list.

For example I would make a list called animals which would include 3 animals, lion tiger and fish. is is possible to offer selected elements from a list. I'm pretty sure it is but I just don't know how.

I was thinking something like this (obviously wrong but I think it helps to understand what I mean)

```
animals = ['Lion', 'Tiger', 'Fish']

print "which of these animals is your favourite?"
favourite = raw_input(animals[0] or animals[2])
if favourite = "Lion':
    print "Nice choice"
else:
    print "Bad choice"
```

Again I can't stress enough I know the above is really crap but essentially I want to offer certain items of a list as an option for the raw_input. In the above case the 0 item and the 2 item.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
favourite = raw_input(' or '.join(animals))
```

This will take all the strings from the list `animals` and join them together with `or` in between, so you'll end up with

```
Lion or Tiger or Fish
```

if you want to add a question mark and space to the end, you can do

```
favourite = raw_input(' or '.join(animals) + '? ')
```

Also, on the line

```
if favourite = "Lion':
```

Your quotes don't match -- make sure to use either double or single quotes, not one of each. You also need to use `==` to compare two things; `=` is for assigning a value, not comparing.

I would probably do it like

```
animal_string = ' or '.join(animals)
favourite = raw_input("Which of these animals is your favourite:\n{}? ".format(animal_string))
```

Which first makes the animal string, then formats the choices into the question on a new line (because of the `\n`), and puts `?` after.

Comment: wow I can't believe how quick stuff gets answered on here! Thanks so much. To add to that though if I only wanted to pick two of the animals how would I do that rather than list all of the animals?

Comment: @Craig `' or '.join(animals[x] for x in (0, 2))` is a good way. This puts the indexes in a tuple `(0, 2)`, and then creates a generator expression (basically a loop) that gets the item at each index from `animals`. The `join` function then runs the generator, and joins the values it yields.

Comment: @steabert You've got to change that version a lot more if the number of animals you want changes -- my version works basically unchanged for any number of animals.

Comment: that is true, that's why i gave you a +1, mine is not so flexible

Comment: @steabert your version is definitely simpler :)

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
favourite = raw_input("which of these animals is your favourite? "+",".join([str(a)+":"+b for a,b in enumerate(animals)])+">")
fav = animals[int(favourite)]
print fav+" is a nice choice indeed!. The big bear will kill you anyway. Good bye."
```

Comment: Thanks for your help bpgergo, I think that's a bit advanced for me at the moment, there is so much in there that I can't understand. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: @Craig `enumerate` gives index, value for each item in animals `(0, Lion)`, `(1, Tiger)`, `(2, Fish)`. He then joins together the index and value with a colon between `1:Tiger`, then joins these together with a comma in between `0:Lion,1:Tiger,2:Fish`. You then put in the number of the animal you like, and he converts the entered string into an integer `int(favourite)` and looks that animal up in the list, then tells you that was a nice choice.

Comment: @Craig, sorry for going beyond your depth. I just tried to give an answer which is somewhat generalize the problem of letting the user choose an element from a list via row_input. Anyway, Zed Shaw's book is the best way to start programming (and Python), so just keep it up.